# SQL retrieve string that have special character

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, text, data-retrieval

I am trying to write a query that select only the values that have a '+' at the end.

These values are pieces of text that users select from a screen that serves them a list of reference comments. The different special characters that a pieces of text can have at the end are: '+' or '~' or '|'

The values are stored in a single column, and are mixed.

For this task I only need to get the comments that end with a '+'.

Here is an example of the text that is stored:

```
    Addendum and/or contract providing additional event details and conditions.+

There are charges for these services.+

Notify Mall Crew of electrical needs for activities.+

Provide and maintain access to the Hotel1 during event.~

Provide and maintain access to the Hotel2 during event.~

Event organizer/sponsor is responsible for cleanup of event area1.|

Event organizer/sponsor is responsible for cleanup of event area2.|
```

Here is my query (not working) it returns nothing.

```
SELECT
    COMMENT
FROM 
    PERMIT A
INNER JOIN 
    PROCESS G ON A.CODE = G.CODE 
WHERE  
    RIGHT(COMMENT, 2) = '+'
    AND COMMENT <> ''
```

[image]

Thank you much in advance for your help.

Comment: Try `where comment like '%\r%` and `where comment like '%\r` - you might have whitespace at the end of your comments that is messing up your right 2.

Comment: Do you mean `\r` as in "a backslash character followed by a lowercase r", or do you mean "a carriage return, as symbolized by the `\r` escape sequence supported in many C-like languages"? In other words, are you seeing these characters directly in your database or as escaped values in client code somewhere?

Comment: @APH that could very easily return false positives if the is \r in the middle somewhere.

Comment: @SeanLange definitely (that's why I didn't post it as an answer) - but it could help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Everything after the RIGHT is just noise. How could a comment be NULL and the LEN not be longer than 0? and if the length is longer than 0 how could it be an empty string? I would think a simple "LIKE '%\r'" would be a simpler replacement for the entire where clause than all that stuff. But as @JeroenMostert pointed out, you may not really be looking for that string and are instead looking for a char(10) or char(13)

Comment: `\r` often means the ascii special "carriage return" which has a value of 13.  `\n` often means new line (or line feed) which has a value of 10.  On windows in text files you see both of these at the end of lines in unix you only see carriage return.  I'm guessing this is what you are looking for.  If so you have to convert the line to binary and compare the ending values

Comment: helpful reference => https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert, I meant a backslash character followed by a lowercase r

Comment: I am looking for the string, not the carriage return. Thanks

Comment: Replacing everything with the LIKE '%\r%' returns every comment, just as the example I included above, it does not filter the string with \n, again this is the actual text, not the new line feed.

Comment: I copied the text from the table column, and pasted it in notepad ++, then I turned all characters on, and took a screen shot of it. I uploaded it to show how the comments are stored, There seems to be a carriage returns and line feed after the '\r' character. Do you have any advice? Thank you.

Comment: What's the data type on the comment column?

Comment: @Eric Brandt, varchar(4000)

Comment: I updated the special character to remove confusion, now I am using +, or ~, or | at the end of the different string comments. For this task, I only need to retrieve all comments that end with a '+' sign. Thank you.

Comment: And the sample data you have posted. Does that represent one row of data, or seven rows of data?

Comment: 1 row only, all the values in one column, and mixed usually the order goes like: comments with '+' in the end go first, then comments with '~', last, comments with '|'

Comment: When I see it in SSMS, I see only one row, when I copy and paste the contents of the column in notepadd ++, it gets pasted as shown on the screen shot. I do not enter manually the empty lines.

Comment: @erasmocarlos ah, that explains it!  The `right` function you're using looks at the last two characters in a cell.  What you want to do is strip out any characters (comments) that aren't between a carriage return and a `+` line ender, correct?

Comment: I did not know that about the RIGHT function but I get it now.

Comment: The idea of having comments that end with different special characters, was to help differentiate them when extracting them and eventually putting them on a report. The different special characters, represent groups of characters. Does that make sense? I hope someone can offer a helping hand. Thank you kindly.

Comment: string_split may help. May I know which version of your SQL Server is?

Comment: Your issue is you are storing multiple lines in a single varchar and you need to parse out the "lines" that end in +.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I did not test this, it may have typos, but the basic idea is to convert your text into XML and then use the XML tools to query the result.  This is much easier than trying to parse a string with a dynamic number of lines.

First we extract the xml string from the table converting the whole thing to an xml string with rows for each line and use replace on the CR LF to make seperators:

```
SET @xmlstr  = 
  SELECT CAST('<file><row>' + REPLACE(COMMENT,CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),'</row><row>') + '</row></file>' AS XML)
  FROM PERMIT A
  INNER JOIN PROCESS G ON A.CODE = G.CODE
```

Then select the lines you want from the XML

```
SELECT line.a_row
FROM    @xmlstr.nodes('/file') AS line(a_row)
WHERE right(line.a_row,1) = '+'
```

You can find many examples of using this trick (converting to xml to aid in parsing) on this website and around the web.

Comment: Hello Hogan, I was sick for the last couple of days and out of work. I just returned today and will give your recommendation a try. Thank you for your help, I will report whether I make it work or not. Best regards.

Comment: I am trying to retrieve the contents of the XML column but I get an error message: The column 'a_row' that was returned from the nodes() method cannot be used directly. It can only be used with one of the four XML data type methods, exist(), nodes(), query(), and value(), or in IS NULL and IS NOT NULL checks.

Comment: I made it work. It does return the text with a '+) in the end. The problem now is that I have 3 sentences that have a '+' and the SELECT only returns the first one. Do you have any advice to work around this?

Comment: '<file>
  <row>Addendum and/or contract providing additional event details and conditions. +</row>
  <row />
  <row>Special duty officer(s) required for event. There are charges for these services.+</row>
  <row />
  <row>Notify Mall Crew of electrical needs for activities.+</row>
  <row />
  <row>8’ pedestrian pathway must be maintained on sidewalks throughout event area.~</row>
  <row />
  <row>Provide and maintain access to the Hotel during event.~</row>
  <row />
  <row>Event organizer/sponsor is responsible for cleanup of event area. |</row>
  <row />  
</file>'

Comment: @erasmocarlos my select statement should have returned all 3